# How can I set my eclipse and tomcat?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have two problems... I cannot decode and run my projects.

1. I met this error

org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.FeatureNotFoundException: Feature 'servlet-name' not found.

What does this error mean?

2. When I access Tomcat I get the following error, 'starting Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost failed to start. '

and in the console window I get this,

```
4월 11, 2017 6:34:54 오후 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
경고: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:InnoToolsFactory' did not find a matching property.
4월 11, 2017 6:34:54 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.43
4월 11, 2017 6:34:54 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: Server built:          Mar 28 2017 14:42:59 UTC
4월 11, 2017 6:34:54 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: Server number:         8.0.43.0
4월 11, 2017 6:34:54 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: OS Name:               Windows 7
4월 11, 2017 6:34:54 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: OS Version:            6.1
4월 11, 2017 6:34:54 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: Architecture:          amd64
4월 11, 2017 6:34:54 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121
4월 11, 2017 6:34:54 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: JVM Version:           1.8.0_121-b13
4월 11, 2017 6:34:54 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
4월 11, 2017 6:34:54 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: CATALINA_BASE:         E:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
4월 11, 2017 6:34:54 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\itf01\Desktop\KS\홈피작업\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.43
4월 11, 2017 6:34:54 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=E:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
4월 11, 2017 6:34:54 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\itf01\Desktop\KS\홈피작업\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.43
4월 11, 2017 6:34:54 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=E:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
4월 11, 2017 6:34:54 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Users\itf01\Desktop\KS\홈피작업\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.43\endorsed
4월 11, 2017 6:34:54 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
4월 11, 2017 6:34:54 오후 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
정보: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v91\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\Bandizip\7z;C:\Users\itf01\Desktop\eGovFrameDev-3.6.0-64bit\eclipse;;.
4월 11, 2017 6:34:54 오후 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
정보: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
4월 11, 2017 6:34:54 오후 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
정보: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
4월 11, 2017 6:34:54 오후 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
정보: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
4월 11, 2017 6:34:54 오후 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
정보: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
4월 11, 2017 6:34:54 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
정보: Initialization processed in 1147 ms
4월 11, 2017 6:34:55 오후 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
정보: Starting service Catalina
4월 11, 2017 6:34:55 오후 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
정보: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.43
4월 11, 2017 6:34:58 오후 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
심각: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Cuppool].StandardWrapper[null]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:135)
at     org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addChild(StandardContext.java:2835)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1381)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1193)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:783)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:307)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5213)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Util.objectNameValueNeedsQuote(Util.java:26)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.getObjectNameKeyProperties(StandardWrapper.java:1805)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase.initInternal(LifecycleMBeanBase.java:61)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.initInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
... 18 more

4월 11, 2017 6:34:58 오후 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
심각: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Cuppool]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Cuppool]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Cuppool].StandardWrapper[null]]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:757)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addChild(StandardContext.java:2835)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1381)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1193)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:783)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:307)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5213)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
... 6 more

4월 11, 2017 6:34:58 오후 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
심각: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:789)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
... 6 more

4월 11, 2017 6:34:58 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
심각: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
at     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:789)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
... 11 more

4월 11, 2017 6:34:58 오후 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
정보: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
4월 11, 2017 6:34:58 오후 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
정보: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
4월 11, 2017 6:34:58 오후 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
정보: Stopping service Catalina
4월 11, 2017 6:34:58 오후 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
정보: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
4월 11, 2017 6:34:58 오후 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
심각: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:315)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:491)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:883)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:551)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:879)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

4월 11, 2017 6:34:58 오후 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
정보: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
4월 11, 2017 6:34:58 오후 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
심각: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:315)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:491)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:883)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:551)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:879)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

4월 11, 2017 6:34:58 오후 org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase destroy
경고: Calling stop() on failed component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Cuppool]] to trigger clean-up did not complete.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to stop component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Cuppool]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:860)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1040)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:860)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1040)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:604)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:879)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to stop component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Cuppool].StandardWrapper[null]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source
at java.util.EventObject.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.management.Notification.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.stopInternal(StandardWrapper.java:1786)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
... 20 more

4월 11, 2017 6:34:58 오후 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase removeChild
심각: ContainerBase.removeChild: destroy: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to destroy component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Cuppool]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:860)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1040)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:860)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1040)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:604)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
at     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:879)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component [org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl@1b68ddbd] in state [STARTED]
at         org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:395)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:287)
at     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.destroyInternal(StandardContext.java:5637)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
... 17 more
```

How can I solve these problems?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Server Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost failed to start. ...what's this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335491/server-tomcat-v8-0-server-at-localhost-failed-to-start-whats-this)

Comment: That is my Question..

Comment: We are not encourage to post duplicate question. Edit your previous question and it will be bumped to top of queue when it get edited.